# Drawable is not getting displayed

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-drawable

The drawable is not getting displayed

circle_add.xml in drawable

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#000000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="-90">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#000000" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

I have used it inside the editText

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/member_email"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:background="#d4d4d4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/circle_add"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="36dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="312dp" />
```

But it is not getting displayed inside the textbox.

[image]

How to make it appear at the end of the textbox.

Comment: try with android:drawableEnd ="@drawable/circle_add"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define the size of it.

Copy the below codes and try again. it will be shown.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <size
                android:height="10dp"
                android:width="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="-90">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```